# return a mathematical function as string

Tags: python, matplotlib

suppose I have a function:

```
  def func(t):
      a=5;b=-7;c=4;d=2
      return a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d
```

beside returning the value of the function, I am also trying to get the function literally, as, when called, I will get:

```
a*t**3 +b*t**2+c*t +d = <actual mathematical value>
```

My final goal is to get it correct as a `LaTeX` expression to write the statement in `matplotlib`.

Any help?

**UPDATE** Dear all, Thanks for your reply. But I just don't want to write the function once again, as you have shown, is some way like:

```
return "a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d = " + str(a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d)
```

(I can easier do that in `plt.txt` directly, right?)

I just want to transform the function copied literally:

```
def func(t):
  a=.05;b=-.07;c=.04;d=.02
  return a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d

def strf():
  #  return(r"$a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d$")
  return (str(func))   
  # expecting this to give the output
  #  r"$a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
def func(t):
    a = 5
    b = -7
    c = 4
    d = 2
    return "a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d = " + str(a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(t):
    a = 5
    b = -7
    c = 4
    d = 2
    exp = "a*t**3+b*t**2+c*t+d"
    return f"{exp} = {eval(exp)}"
```

I think this is it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f-string:

```
def func(t):
    a = 5
    b = -7
    c = 4
    d = 2
    result = a * t**3 + b * t**2 + c * t + d
    return result, f'a * t**3 + b * t**2 + c * t + d = {result}'

res, str_ = func(5)

print(res)
print(str_)
```

Output:

```
472
a * t**3 + b * t**2 + c * t + d = 472
```

I don‘t recommend you to use the function `eval()` as in another solutions.